# Haskell - Sorting sublist

Tags: haskell

I have a list with some sublists and I need to order it by length.

For example:
`[[1,3,4,9],[2,4],[5,4,7]]` would become `[[2,4],[5,4,7],[1,3,4,9]]`.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working with that?

Comment: Do not change your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [**`sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) to sort items in a list based on the result of a function called on the elements, for example:

```
Prelude> import Data.List(sortOn)
Prelude Data.List> sortOn length [[1,3,4,9],[2,4],[5,4,7]]
[[2,4],[5,4,7],[1,3,4,9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`comparing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) to generate a custom comparison function with the `length` function, the sort the list with the builtin [`sortBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) function:

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

x :: [[Int]]
x = sortBy (comparing length) [[1,3,4,9],[2,4],[5,4,7]]
-- x == [[2,4],[5,4,7],[1,3,4,9]]
```